# Trying to compile QGIS but it complains it can't find QGIS library

Tags: qgis, windows-7, compilation

I'm trying to compile QGIS in Windows7 with a MSYS, with the objective of making a QGIS Windows App using the API.  I am using this [document](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.1.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf).

I'm using CMake-GUI and it gives the error

> Warning Target "qgis_core" requests linking to directory
>   "c:\OSGeo4W\bin".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is
>   dropping the item.]

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKW7c.jpg)

I think its looking for qgis_core.lib, but I don't think it exists because I want to compile it... so this error makes no sense to me.

Comment: use make VERBOSE=1 # to get the actual compiler/linker output. The link paths should be visible there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did a lot of things wrong.

1. I downloaded the QGIS-Master instead of QGIS-Release 1.8 (2.0 did not compile for me)
2. I configured to build with MSys instead of Visual Studio 10
3. I copied my Bison.exe bin to OSGeo4W/bin not realizing that it relys on a lot of files relative to the directory especially m4sugar.m4
4. I had to do a cmake-gui in the GQGIS-Release files
5. I didn't immediately realize cmake generated nice Visual Studio Solution files for me
6. I got hung up on some XML "errors" that are actually just warnings can be ignored.
7. I tried to compile against Qt5, and it only compiles against Qt4

But now it compiles! OS GEO HERE I COME!